Using actions/checkout@v4: Write access to repository not granted
When I try to download a different repository within my organization using actions/checkout@v4 and a fine-grained access token with "Read access to code and metadata", I'm getting "Write access to repository not granted."
##[group]Fetching the repository
[command]/usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +refs/heads/production*:refs/remotes/origin/production* +refs/tags/production*:refs/tags/production*
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
##[error]fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/acme-integrations/myrepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128

Note the token is installed as a repo secret GH_AUTH_TOKEN, and I'm passing it in properly.
actions/checkout@v4
- name: "Checkout Deps: MyDeps"
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    repository: acme-integrations/myrepo
    ref: production
    path: foo/bar/baz
    token: ${{ secrets.GH_AUTH_TOKEN }}

My token has read-access to "Contents" and "Meta-Contents" it shouldn't need to write to anything to use actions/checkout,


My problem was that the plugin was "waiting admin approval" which is something it never told me I needed when I created it.
Here is a screen shot.

An admin approved it, and it worked.
